# Console loging a double array from a solidity function?

Tags: javascript, chai, solidity

I'm doing chai tests and want to get a double array from a smart contract function and console log it.
My function:

```
function getBuyOrderBook(string symbolName) constant returns (uint[], uint[]) {
    uint8 tokenNameIndex = getSymbolIndexOrThrow(symbolName);
    uint[] memory arrPricesBuy = new uint[](tokens[tokenNameIndex].amountBuyPrices);//length of the prices
    uint[] memory arrVolumesBuy = new uint[](tokens[tokenNameIndex].amountBuyPrices);

       

        uint whilePrice = tokens[tokenNameIndex].lowestBuyPrice;
        uint counter = 0;
        if(tokens[tokenNameIndex].curBuyPrice > 0){ 
            while(whilePrice <= tokens[tokenNameIndex].curBuyPrice ){

                arrPricesBuy[counter] = whilePrice;
                
                uint volumeAtPrice = 0;

                uint offers_key = 0;
                offers_key = tokens[tokenNameIndex].buyBook[whilePrice].offers_key;

                while(tokens[tokenNameIndex].buyBook[whilePrice].offers_length >= offers_key){

                    volumeAtPrice += tokens[tokenNameIndex].buyBook[whilePrice].offers[offers_key].amount;//increase the amount(i.e. 10 tokens) to this price (i.e. 10$)
                    offers_key ++; //
                   
                }
                arrVolumesBuy[counter] = volumeAtPrice;
                if(whilePrice == tokens[tokenNameIndex].buyBook[whilePrice].higherPrice){ 

                    break;
                }
                else{
                    whilePrice == tokens[tokenNameIndex].buyBook[whilePrice].higherPrice ; 

                }
            counter ++; 

        }
           

            

    }

        return (arrPricesBuy, arrVolumesBuy ) ;


}
```

But dont know how to console log the promise so I can return the two arrays :

```
 let arr1 = [];
 let arr2 = [];

 arr1,arr2 =  await exchangeInstance.getArr(tokenSymbol);
 console.log(arr1, arr2);
```

This clearly doesnt work, any suggestions ?

Thank you

Comment: Have you tried `a = await exchangeInstance.getArr(tokenSymbol); console.log(a)`? or `let [arr1, arr2] = await exchangeInstance.getArr(tokenSymbol);`? (in the second case you do not need `let arr1` and `let arr2` lines)

Comment: Try changing your returned value: `return [myArr1,myArr2]` in getArr function.

Comment: It is hard to tell you, because there is so little code in your question.. I have to guess what you need... Ok, what is the result of `getArr` function? Is it an array-of-arrays?

Comment: Hmm,ok, I tried : let items = [[],[]];
        items = await exchangeInstance.getBuyOrderBook(tokenSymbol);
        console.table(items);  And it works, but only if i have one order and the output should be 1,100. Every array holds two values... If I make another order and the output should be [1,100] [2,200] it gives me the invalid upcode error? also  tried changing the returned value in my function,like u suggested,  to return [myArr1,myArr2], but got the :TypeError:Unable to deduce common type for array elements ?

Comment: So to explain a bit more my getArr Function and what it should return... The myArr1 retruns the accumulative  amount of one value and the myArr2 another accumulative value. So I should be able to return myArr1,myArr2 :  [20][1]; [50][2];[10][4]...This are 3 orders, Im building an exchange, so those are 3 order book values...One arary is for volume and another for price,  I can also paste the whole function code if you wish? Thx

Comment: The only question is what `getArr` returns. If it return array-of-arrays - this is one option. If it returns object with arrays inside - this is another option. If it returns a tuple, then we see option 1 (array of arrays).

Comment: Ive updated my question post with the entire function. Hope it clears things up...sorry I didnt do it in the begining... Thx

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, man, I can't recognize what JavaScript language subset is this, but in pure JS it will be something like that:

```js
function getBuyOrderBook(symbolName) {
  const arr1 = []; // our generated array 1
  const arr2 = []; // our generated array 2
  arr1.push.apply(arr1, [1, 2, 3]); // some operations with array 1
  arr2.push.apply(arr2, [4, 5, 6]); // some operations with array 2
  return [arr1, arr2]; // return combined result
}

let [a1, a2] = /*await*/ getBuyOrderBook(); // unpack result into 2 variables

console.log('a1 =', a1); // show var 1
console.log('a2 =', a2); // show var 2
```

Does this make sense to you?

Comment: The function Im calling is in solidity and the chai tests are in javascript...so this code doesnt compile... thx for the input, really appriciate it... this is what Ive got so far and Im able to return one order...   expect(await exchangeInstance.buyToken(tokenSymbol, 200, 2));
        //expect(await exchangeInstance.buyToken(tokenSymbol, 100, 1));but  if I add this order I get an error : invalid opcode ?? 
        
        let items = [[],[]];
        
        items = await exchangeInstance.getBuyOrderBook(tokenSymbol);
        console.table(items);